# Shoud a sitemap include favicon.ico and robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, favicon

Should a sitemap include favicon.ico and robots.txt?  They are in mine (and do exist) and I'm worried removing them will cause some problem.

Answer (score 3):

A sitemap is for pages that need indexing.  A `robots.txt` is usually found in the root folder.  And a `favicon` is specified by the meta tag in the webpages.  So there is no need to list them elsewhere.

Since `robots.txt` and `favicon` are not indexed, it is completely safe to remove them.

> **What Is a Sitemap?**
> A sitemap is a file that contains the website’s structure. It helps search engines understand the connection between web pages, identifying the most important ones.

From [What Is a Sitemap](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-a-sitemap)